# How is this code using numbers to identify a letter as a upper or lowercase

Tags: python

I was looking for code that would take in a string and output the number of uppercase and lowercase letters in that string. I stumbled upon this solution, but I don't understand how it's using numbers to identify whether a letter is upper or lowercase.

```
# Python3 program to count upper and 
# lower case characters without using 
# inbuilt functions 
def upperlower(string): 

    upper = 0
    lower = 0

    for i in range(len(string)): 

        # For lower letters 
        if (ord(string[i]) >= 97 and
            ord(string[i]) <= 122): 
            lower += 1

        # For upper letters 
        elif (ord(string[i]) >= 65 and
            ord(string[i]) <= 90): 
            upper += 1

    print('Lower case characters = %s' %lower, 
        'Upper case characters = %s' %upper) 

# Driver Code 
string = 'GeeksforGeeks is a portal for Geeks'
upperlower(string)
```

Output

```
Lower case characters = 27 Upper case characters = 3
```

Comment: Did you read the docs to see what ord does? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ord()`: Returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string

As the unicode of lower case(65-90)

```
elif (ord(string[i]) >= 65 and ord(string[i]) <= 90):
```

and upper case(97-122) alphabets are different

```
elif (ord(string[i]) >= 65 and ord(string[i]) <= 90):
```

By knowing comparing the unicode the program counts the alphabets